# Cannot install R updates because they "requre installation of untrusted packages", can't update expired key either (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)

Tags: 16.04, updates, r, keyserver

I've had this problem for some time. First, I tried to update my software through Software Updater. I succeeded for all packages except the R (open source stat software) packages. I got the following error message stating

> This requires installing packages from unauthenticated sources.

I then tried to update the packages through Terminal:

`sudo apt-get update`

It didn't work.

````
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexlarsson/flatpak/ubuntu xenial InRelease     
Ign:3 http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates xenial-dell-service InRelease  
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                
Hit:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Ign:6 http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates xenial-dell-turis-vegas-mlk-kbl InRelease
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease              
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/codeblocks-devs/release/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Hit:9 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Hit:10 http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates xenial-dell InRelease         
Hit:11 http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates xenial-dell-service Release   
Hit:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease             
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nathan-renniewaldock/flux/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:14 http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates xenial-dell-turis-vegas-mlk-kbl Release
Get:15 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran35/ InRelease [3625 B]
Ign:15 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran35/ InRelease
Fetched 3625 B in 0s (4471 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran35/ InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1602869253  KEYEXPIRED 1602869253  KEYEXPIRED 1602869253
W: The repository 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran35/ InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.```


I looked around the web for an answer and I found out that most likely the key has expired so I checked:

```apt-key list|grep "expired:"```

This is the output I got:

```pub   2048R/E084DAB9 2010-10-19 [expired: 2020-10-16]```

Then I tried to renew the expired key:

```gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv E084DAB9```

```gpg: requesting key E084DAB9 from hkp server keys.gnupg.net
?: keys.gnupg.net: Host not found
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect: Success
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
gpg: keyserver communications error: keyserver unreachable
gpg: keyserver communications error: public key not found
gpg: keyserver receive failed: public key not found```

Nothing happened, so I tried again with another keyserver:

```gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv E084DAB9```

```gpg: requesting key E084DAB9 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /home/mainuser/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key E084DAB9: public key "Totally Legit Signing Key <mallory@example.org>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)```

Then I tried ```sudo apt-get update``` again, and got the same error from before. 

Has anyone had the same problem? I have run out of ideas how to fix the expired key issue.

-----------------------

Update - tried this as well 

```gpg --export --armor E084DAB9 | sudo apt-key add - ``` (from askubuntu.com/questions/117015/…), still can't install updates. 

Tried ```sudo apt-get install --allow-unauthenticated exiv2``` as well, no difference.
````

Comment: Not a direct solution to your problem but be aware support and updates for 16.04 stop in April when it reaches EOL. Time to think about an upgrade.

Comment: Updates and additional info best as edit to question not as a comment.

Comment: Canonical, the maker of Ubuntu will continue to support 16.04 through Extended Security Maintenance until April 2024. Ask Ubuntu is currently trying to change policy to make 16.04 off topic. ESM is free and not too hard to set up. I discus a little bit about activating it at this link: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19510/is-ubuntu-14-04-off-topic-on-ask-ubuntu/19529#19529 You can vote to continue Ask Ubuntu support for ESM versions of Ubuntu here: https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/19545/43926

Answer (score 2):

You have to [secure apt](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html#secure-apt) by

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
```

or

```
gpg -a --export E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9 | sudo apt-key add -
```

and then retry with `sudo apt-get update`.

The documentation explains it [here](http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/).